# How to exclude dependency combination of IDs (In the query or after that in loop foreach)?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreach, combinations

I am giving really shorten example of tables structure and the real example. Let's say I have:
Language - **PHP**, DB - **MySQL**

- 1) Table - Attribute_types (id, name)
- 2) Table - Attributes (id, attribute_type_id, name)
- 3) Table - Attributes_dependencies (attribute_id, opposite_attribute_id)

The idea of table 3) is to exclude combination between 2 attributes from different attribute types.

Example:

```
Attribute_types
id | name
1 Size
2 Color
3 Material

Attributes
id | attribute_type_id | name
1 1 S
2 1 M
3 1 L
4 2 Blue
5 2 Red
6 3 Leather
7 3 Silk

Attributes_dependencies
attribute_id | opposite_attribute_id
1 6
7 1
```

The example above shows that we have dependency and combination between (listed below should not exists)

- **S** with **Leather**
- **Silk** with **S**

I need to have combinations like this (2 * 2 * 2 = 8), remember we exclude one from attribute_type 1 (**S**):

```
2-4-6
2-5-6
2-4-7
2-5-7
3-4-6
3-5-6
3-4-7
3-5-7
```

I have to get them as collection(object/array) grouped by attribute_type_id without the dependencies(exclude **S**)

Example:

```
    Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 7
        )
)
```

My Question is how to do this best practiced directly in the query even if there are a few steps before that as preparation, like I gather all IDs in array and use them as Where_in statement or other subqueries.

Because if I do it in foreach loop it does a lot of queries to check if specific combination is valid or not.

Remember I give 1% of my real example, because in real I join 6 more tables and have Thousands combinations not only 8